# Prevent global CSS on certain JSX page

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx, html-framework-7

I am converting old application which using framework7 and html to JSX, but unfortunately on my landing page it disables the scrollbar, which is unwanted. the location of these stylesheets are inside public/index.html
If I comments

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sdgs/framework7/dist/css/framework7.material.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sdgs/framework7/dist/css/framework7.material.colors.css">
```

the application will become normal, but affecting styling other pages.

The question is, how can I prevent this global css to be applied only for the landing page?

Here is what I have tried

```
import styles from "./landingPageStyle.module.css";

const LandingPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={styles.navbar}>
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
                <a href="#news">News</a>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.page}>
                <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
                <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
                <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}

export default LandingPage;
```

and the CSS

```
.navbar{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  
  .navbar a:hover {
    background: green;
    color: black;
  }

.page{
  background-color: yellow;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
```

Resulted
[image]
instead of
[image]

Comment: You should look into CSS modules - that is a great way to control the scope and avoid CSS collisions across the build application.

Comment: I tried with CSS modules, but still not working. Any idea why?

Comment: Is the problem that the styling applies to unwanted pages, or that it does not apply to all pages?

Comment: I want to exclude global styling only for landing page

Comment: Then you must modularly import it to all other pages, as far is im aware

Comment: I am sorry I dont get you, which one needed to be imported modularly?the root cause is <link rel="stylesheet" ref="/sdgs/framework7/dist/css/framework7.material.css"> and 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sdgs/framework7/dist/css/framework7.material.colors.css">, if I disable this all things going well but affect another page

Comment: You should be able to import them in a CSS module and apply them to components specifically, rather than globally. Or, you can overwrite the CSS with other properties (resetting) for the front page